# iterate through something a save it onto an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a var that holds the following information:

```
[[code=666]],[[code=777]],
```

I want to iterate trough those and save `"666"` and `"777"` in an array like `{"666","777"}`. I tried to the the following but it is saving it as `{"6","6, "6", "7", "7", "7"}`.

```js
var t = this;
var regex = /\[\[code=.*?\]\]/gi;
var match = t;
match = t.data.u_pricing.match(regex);

var final_code = [];

if (match != null) {
  //itereate through the matches eg. [[code=666]] [[code=777]]
  for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
    var init_index = match[i].indexOf("=") + 1;
    var end_index = match[i].length - 2;
    for (init_index; init_index < end_index; init_index++) {
      final_code.push(match[i][init_index]);
    }
    console.log("FINAL CODE" + final_code);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're storing `this` in `t`. The content of `t` is then stored in `match` and the value of `match` is then immediately overwritten with the result of `t.data.u_pricing.match()` - Why? O.o

Comment: `"[[code=666]],[[code=777]]".match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: [[code=666]],[[code=777]] was just an example. My match var hold a lot of codes...

Comment: _"My match var hold a lot of codes"_ This doesn't change anything... Did you check the output of `.match(/\d+/g)`?

Answer (score 0):

You've been pushing it letter by letter. You could just use slice() for example.

```
var t = this;
var regex = /\[\[code=.*?\]\]/gi;
var match = t;
match = t.data.u_pricing.match(regex);

var final_code = [];

if (match != null) {
    console.log(match)

  //itereate through the matches eg. [[code=666]] [[code=777]]
  for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
    var init_index = match[i].indexOf("=") + 1;
    var end_index = match[i].length - 2;
    final_code.push(match[i].slice(init_index, end_index))
  }
  console.log(final_code);
}
```

Comment: It kinda works. This is the output : FINAL CODE: 251,51,1,252,52,2  ...it is printing 51 and 1 as well as 52 and 2.

Comment: Strange. Maybe the easiest option is to use answer from Andreas comment to your question. It surely works.

Comment: You see that in my answer there is only one for loop right? Because it seems like you are making more than one loop. I have tested it with "[[code=666]],[[code=777]]" and it worked well. Output was ["666", "777"]. Of course I have hardcoded "[[code=666]],[[code=777]]" instead of t.data.u_pricing.

Comment: could you provide me the code? it is not working for me.

Comment: The code I used is exactly like in answer with exception that instead of `t.data.u_pricing` I write an example of `[[code=666]],[[code=777]]`. Do you use also the implementation from the answer or modified implementation from the question? If latter could you provide whole modified implementation in the question?

Comment: Sorry I don'y get what you are saying, could you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

Since Andreas and barnski answer did not work for you, maybe this will do:

```js
var str = '[[code=666]],[[code=777]]'; // this.data.u_pricing
var regex = /\[\[code=(.*?)\]\]/gi;
var match;

var final_code = [];

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  final_code.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(final_code);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Because if you run the snippet it will give you `["666", "777"]`

Comment: yeah it doesnt worj.

Comment: I don't think how is that compiling if you need an equal sign inside of the while. I tried the exact code in a different compiler and it return nothing,

Comment: The equal sign is just assigning the value of `regex.exec(str)` to `match`, and it will run until it returns `null`. Here is a version using the comparison operator https://repl.it/OGfL/2

Comment: Maybe you could give us an example of the data you're trying to extract the codes from, so we can figure out what is wrong with the regular expressions we are using

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = '[[code=666]],[[code=777]]';
var result = [];
test.split(']]').forEach(function(str) {
    if(str.indexOf('[[code=') != -1) {
        result.push(str.replace('[[code=', ''));
    }
});
console.log(result);
```